# Is there an attribute I can use in net core 6 to restrict my controller to only allow calls which come from a certain paths?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, c#-6.0

For example I have a class:

```
public class AccountsController : Controller
{

[HttpPost, Route("LogIn")]
public LogIn([FromBody] request)
{
 //log in
}

[HttpPost, Route("LogOut")]
public LogOut([FromBody] request)
{
 //log out
}
}
```

I only want these controller endpoints accessible from my site when it does not come straight from the base domain. Example: [www.mysite.com/login](http://www.mysite.com/login) should not work, but [www.mysite.com/uk/login](http://www.mysite.com/uk/login) should work. Note: /uk/ can be anything

Is there any attribute I can use on the class or a constraint in the startup to achieve this? Ive searched for routing templates but nothing seems to work for me.

I have tried to add a constraint in the startup like this

```
endpoint.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "Accounts",
                    constraints: new { accountsConstraint = new AccountsConstraint() },
                    pattern: "",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Accounts" });
```

In the account constraint i am checking if the current site is the base domain but it just bypasses this

Comment: You know that the request can be forged, right?

Comment: @PauloMorgado please explain

Comment: @PauloMorgado also, instead of /uk/ being anything - im happy for a approach where i could specify specifically what is allowed before /login and /logout but it should always be in the format '{domain}/{site}/{action}'- just need to be pointed in the right direction

Comment: What do you mean by "come from"? The requester URL?

Comment: @PauloMorgado I mean my base domain is www.mysite.com - from here it shouldnt be able to access /login. It should only work when there is a site infront of the domain such as www.mysite.com/siteone/login

Comment: When you tagged `[c#-6.0]`, did you actually mean `[.net-6.0]`?

Answer (score 1):

> I only want these controller endpoints accessible from my site when it
> does not come straight from the base domain. Example:
> [www.mysite.com/login](http://www.mysite.com/login) should not work, but [www.mysite.com/uk/login](http://www.mysite.com/uk/login)
> should work. Note: /uk/ can be anything

Well, you can write your own custom [`middleware`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#create-a-middleware-pipeline-with-webapplication) to check if the `request context` is coming from *[www.mysite.com/login](http://www.mysite.com/login)*. It will check if the main domain contains with path `/login`. Means any main domain after `/login` will cause the refusal. Is the way you can implement:

**Middleware:**

```
public class RestrictLoginFromMainDomainMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public RestrictLoginFromMainDomainMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
           
            var pathToRestrict = "/login";

            var host = httpContext.Request.Host.Host;

            var path = httpContext.Request.Path.Value?.ToLower();
         
            var completePath = host + path;

            if (completePath.Contains(pathToRestrict.ToLower()))
            {
                httpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Unauthorized!");
            }
           
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
    }
```

**Register Middleware on Program.cs:**

```cs
app.UseMiddleware<RestrictLoginFromMainDomainMiddleware>();
```

**Note:** Here, you should define the path only which need to restrict. Main domain will autometically be detected. For instance, as you wants to restrict, [www.anymaindomain.com/login](http://www.anymaindomain.com/login), therefore, only define `"/login"`.

**Output:**

[image]

**Another Way:**

```cs
public class RestrictMainDomainLoginMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public RestrictMainDomainLoginMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
        {

            var pathToRestrict = "/login";

            if (httpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(pathToRestrict))
            {

                httpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Unauthorized!");

            }

            await _next(httpContext);
        }
    }
```

**Note:** It will work on this scenario **[www.mysite.com/login](http://www.mysite.com/login)**. Other context which has not been specified in the question has not considered here.